# Can you toggle a regulator device from the terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, device-tree

I've been working on a custom embedded board, and set up a few pins as `regulator-fixed` in a custom device tree - they control power to devices on the board and some drivers need them provided as regulators.

Is there a simple way to toggle these regulators from the terminal? Is there a different regulator type that can be toggled from the terminal? The `state` file and all other files in the device folder is set to read only by default.